# Xor gate with Backpropagation

Tags: python, backpropagation

I am trying to understand how backpropagation works. So I wrote a straight forward script to try to understand it before writing a generalized algorithm.

What the script is trying to do is to train an XOR gate.
My neural network is very simple. 2 inputs, 2 hidden neurons, and 1 output. (Note that the bias are omitted for simplicity)

[image]

(for more information see the images attached at the end)

The problem is that after training the perceptron it doesn't work and I don't know where the problem is. It can be in my equations or in my implementation.

Code:

```
    def xor(self):
        print('xor')
        X = np.array([[1,1],[1,0],[0,1],[0,0]]) #X.shape = (4,2)
        y = np.array([0,1,1,0])
        w0 = np.array([[.9,.1],[.3,.5]]) #random weights layer0
        w1 = np.array([.8,.7]) #random wights layer1

        #forward pass
        youtput=[]
        for i in range(X.shape[0]):#X.shape = (4,2)
            #print('x0', X[i][0])
            #print('x1', X[i][1])
            h0 = self.sig(w0[0,0]*X[i][0] + w0[1,0]*X[i][1])
            h1 = self.sig(w0[0,1]*X[i][0] + w0[1,1]* X[i][1])
            y0 = self.sig(w1[0]* h0 + w1[1] * h1) # shape = (4,)
            youtput.append(y0)
            print('y0',y0)

            #backpropagation
            dey0 = -(y[i]-y0) # y[i] -> desired output | y0 -> output
            deW0_00 = dey0 * y0 * (1 - y0) * w1[0] * h0 * (1 - h0) * X[i][0]
            deW0_01 = dey0 * y0 * (1 - y0) * w1[1] * h1 * (1 - h1) * X[i][0]
            deW0_10 = dey0 * y0 * (1 - y0) * w1[0] * h0 * (1 - h0) * X[i][1]
            deW0_11 = dey0 * y0 * (1 - y0) * w1[1] * h1 * (1 - h1) * X[i][1]
            deW1_00 = dey0 * h0
            deW1_10 = dey0 * h1

            w0[0,0] = self.gradient(w0[0,0], deW0_00)
            w0[0,1] = self.gradient(w0[0,1], deW0_01)
            w0[1,0] = self.gradient(w0[1,0], deW0_10)
            w0[1,1] = self.gradient(w0[1,1], deW0_11)
            w1[0] = self.gradient(w1[0], deW1_00)
            w1[1] = self.gradient(w1[1], deW1_10)

            #print('print W0, ', w0)
            #print('print W1, ', w1)
        print('error -> ', self.error(y,youtput ))  
        #forward pass
        youtput2= []
        for i in range(X.shape[0]):#X.shape = (4,2)
            print('x0 =', X[i][0], ', x1 =', X[i][1])
            h0 = self.sig(w0[0,0]*X[i][0] + w0[1,0]*X[i][1])
            h1 = self.sig(w0[0,1]*X[i][0] + w0[1,1]* X[i][1])
            y0 = self.sig(w1[0]* h0 + w1[1] * h1)
            youtput2.append(y0)
            print('y0----->',y0)
        print('error -> ', self.error(y,youtput2 ))

    def gradient(self, w, w_derivative):
        alpha = .001
        for i in range(1000000):
            w = w - alpha * w_derivative
        return w

    def error(self, y, yhat):
        e = 0
        for i in range (y.shape[0]):
            e = e + .5 * (y[i]- yhat[i])**2
        return e 

    def sig(self,x):
         return 1 / (1 + math.exp(-x))
```

Result

```
PS C:\gitProjects\perceptron> python .\perceptron.py
xor
y0 0.7439839341840395
y0 0.49999936933995615
y0 0.4999996364775347
y0 7.228146514841657e-229
error ->  0.5267565442535
x0 = 1 , x1 = 1
y0-----> 0.49999999999999856
x0 = 1 , x1 = 0
y0-----> 0.4999993695274945
x0 = 0 , x1 = 1
y0-----> 0.49999963653435153
x0 = 0 , x1 = 0
y0-----> 7.228146514841657e-229
error ->  0.3750004969693411
```

The equations.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Maybe this can be helpful? https://towardsdatascience.com/implementing-the-xor-gate-using-backpropagation-in-neural-networks-c1f255b4f20d

Comment: I would also like to see how you train the network

Comment: I don't know anything about neural networks, but I did notice your code is incomplete. It's missing imports, the `class` statement, and main.

Comment: @t_e_o the network is trained using gradient descent. In my code, I have a function called gradient. This function takes the derivative respect to the weight we want to update, then we use the gradient descent algorithm to update the weights. In order to see the equation check my notes after I write "In order to calculate the gradient"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just changed the way you "loop", it seems to be working fine now (modified code hereunder).

I may have missed something but **your backprop looks ok**.

```py
import numpy as np
import math

class perceptronmonocouche(object):
    def xor(self):
        print('xor')
        X = np.array([[1,1],[1,0],[0,1],[0,0]]) #X.shape = (4,2)
        y = np.array([0,1,1,0])
        w0 = np.array([[.9,.1],[.3,.5]]) #random weights layer0
        w1 = np.array([.8,.7]) #random wights layer1
        max_epochs = 10000
        epochs = 0
        agreed_convergence_error = 0.001
        error = 1
        decision_threshold = 0.5

        while epochs <= max_epochs and error > agreed_convergence_error:
            #forward pass
            epochs += 1
            youtput=[]
            for i in range(X.shape[0]):#X.shape = (4,2)
                #print('x0', X[i][0])
                #print('x1', X[i][1])
                h0 = self.sig(w0[0,0]*X[i][0] + w0[1,0]*X[i][1])
                h1 = self.sig(w0[0,1]*X[i][0] + w0[1,1]* X[i][1])
                y0 = self.sig(w1[0]* h0 + w1[1] * h1) # shape = (4,)
                youtput.append(y0)
                if epochs%1000 ==0:
                    print('y0',y0)
                    if y0 > decision_threshold:
                        prediction = 1
                    else:
                        prediction = 0
                    print('real value', y[i])
                    print('predicted value', prediction)

                #backpropagation
                dey0 = -(y[i]-y0) # y[i] -> desired output | y0 -> output            
                dew0_00 = dey0 * y0 * (1 - y0) * w1[0] * h0 * (1 - h0) * X[i][0]
                dew0_01 = dey0 * y0 * (1 - y0) * w1[1] * h1 * (1 - h1) * X[i][0]
                dew0_10 = dey0 * y0 * (1 - y0) * w1[0] * h0 * (1 - h0) * X[i][1]
                dew0_11 = dey0 * y0 * (1 - y0) * w1[1] * h1 * (1 - h1) * X[i][1]
                dew1_0 = dey0 * h0
                dew1_1 = dey0 * h1

                w0[0,0] = self.gradient(w0[0,0], dew0_00)
                w0[0,1] = self.gradient(w0[0,1], dew0_01)
                w0[1,0] = self.gradient(w0[1,0], dew0_10)
                w0[1,1] = self.gradient(w0[1,1], dew0_11)
                w1[0] = self.gradient(w1[0], dew1_0)
                w1[1] = self.gradient(w1[1], dew1_1)

                #print('print W0, ', w0)
                #print('print W1, ', w1)
            error = self.error(y,youtput )
            if epochs%1000 ==0:
                print('error -> ', error)

    def gradient(self, w, w_derivative):
        alpha = .2
        w = w - alpha * w_derivative
        return w

    def error(self, y, yhat):
        e = 0
        for i in range (y.shape[0]):
            e = e + .5 * (y[i]- yhat[i])**2
        return e 

    def sig(self,x):
         return 1 / (1 + math.exp(-x))

p = perceptronmonocouche()
p.xor()
```

Result

```py
y0 0.05892656406522486
real value 0
predicted value 0
y0 0.9593864604895951
real value 1
predicted value 1
y0 0.9593585562506973
real value 1
predicted value 1
y0 0.03119936553811551
real value 0
predicted value 0
error ->  0.003873463452052477
```

***Note*** : Here it works fine without the bias, however I'd recommend anytime you can to let the bias for the propagation.

Comment: Thanks, I was wrong on how the gradient is calculated. I was making just one forward pass and looping in the gradient which was doing something with the weights that didn´t work but instead, I needed to make a forward pass each time to calculate the gradient again. I also modified my question with some of you remaks.

Comment: @mavi Yep, I removed my remarks as they are not relevant anymore, and only let a recommendation to use the bias every time.
Good luck with the generalization of your script !